# The origin of my Google login and registration API for my website

Tags: authentication, location, privacy-policy

I have a query. As I am in the process of preparing my privacy policy to ensure its compliance within my country, I am seeking guidance on how to determine the origin of the service associated with the social login via Google that I've integrated into my website. Specifically, I'm interested in knowing whether the service originates from the United States, Ireland, or any other location. Although I have successfully set up social login through my API and everything is functioning properly, this specific clarification is essential for me to proceed.

Nothing, just this question.